# Stopping/Resetting a Function in Java if Validation Criteria is not met

Tags: java, function, validation

I am using this function below to check a value entered in a textbox and if it's valid under the try catch criterias, the function should return a True via the boolean Variable. The program is set up so the final calculation only happens if all my inputs come back as being OK or true in this case.

What I need to get working properly is the return for the try, if the number is not valid the function should stop and get the user to try again, I'm thinking of something like an Exit Sub from VB.  My searches have turned up to use a return like I have below, but that just causes an error since the compiler thinks I am trying to return a function result.

There is a tiny bit more to the function, but I cut it out since it is irrelevant; it's pretty much just the `bGarage = true;` and `return bGarage;`.

```
public boolean fnGarageLevel() {//Beginning of Garage Validation Function

    int nGarage;
    boolean bGarage;

    try {//Garage Number Validation Try

        nGarage = Integer.parseInt(tfGarage.getText());

     if (nGarage != 1 || nGarage != 2 || nGarage != 3 || nGarage != 4) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,
                     "Enter a valid Garage Level, 1, 2, 3 or 4",
                     "Error",
                     JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                     tfGarage.setText("");
                     tfGarage.grabFocus();
                     return;

            }//End of Error Message

    }//End of try

    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {//Beginning of Catch

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Value Entered for Garage is not a Number",
                        "Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        tfGarage.setText("");
        tfGarage.grabFocus();

    }//End of Catch for Garage field

    bGarage = true;
    return bGarage;

}//End of Garage Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `try` section finishes its running successfully (that is, without catching any exception), the control goes right to the end of `catch` section or (if it exists) enters the section `finally`. In this case, the control jumps to `bGarage=true` sentence when the `try` ends. Remove the `return;` statement, it's not necessary.